# spring ldap template authentication

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I am trying to authenticate user via spring ldap. Following is the code to initialise ldap template.

```
contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setUrl("ldaps://ldap.example.com");
contextSource.setBase("DC=example,DC=com");
contextSource.setUserDn("backend-app");
contextSource.setPassword("password");
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

PoolingContextSource pooledContextSource = new PoolingContextSource(); 
pooledContextSource.setDirContextValidator(new 
DefaultDirContextValidator());
pooledContextSource.setContextSource(contextSource);

ldapTemplate =  new LdapTemplate(pooledContextSource); 
ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
```

When i try to use ldapTemplate authenticate method it returns false.

```
// below line fails
ldapTemplate.authenticate("OU=Service Accounts,OU=Pseudo-Users", "frontend-web", "password");
```

But when i use directory context it works

```
DirContext ctx = null;
try {
  ctx = contextSource.getContext("frontend-web", "password");
  return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Login failed", e);
  return false;
} finally {
  LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);  
}
```

**Question 1 :** Is there anyway to make ldaptemplate authenticate method to work?

**Question 2 :** Why don't we have to provide baseDn when we use DirectoryContext directly. How does ldap know where to find the user "frontend-web". Does it search the whole directory for the user "frontend-web"

Can anybody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1** - I ran into the exact same issue....still haven't figured out how to use my existing LDAP template.  I injected the ldap config into my service directly and created a new "private" ldapTemplate that isn't pooled, like so:

```
public class AuthController {

    private final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    AuthController(MyLdapConfig config) {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(config.getUrl());
        contextSource.setUserDn(config.getUserDn());
        contextSource.setPassword(config.getPassword());
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        if (authenticateUser(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }
        log.warn("authentication failed for {}", authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }

    // authenticateUser method omitted
}
```

**Question 2** - yes

> the search always starts at the root of the tree (the empty path)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/#basic-authentication

Comment: update - I just created a new @Bean that was my "AuthTemplate" and created it just like I did my ldapTemplate, minus pooling.  I then constructor inject the AuthTemplate bean into my service.....makes testing much easier